# Alternative way to make custom segmented controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Dragging and dropping a segmented controller from object library is so easy but that one is not always the requirement. I need to implement custom underline type segmented controller but I found it so difficult. The codes I found online are just going above my head. Can someone suggest easy implementation of underline type custom segmented controller?

Comment: like thing  ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layman and the easiest approach could be that, you place two labels on your view. and under each label you place one progress bar. Make progress bars hidden by default. Create @IBOutlets for these progress bars and labels. Assign constraints carefully. Now drag a segmented controller from object library and place over these. Make the tint as clear/transparent. Create outlets for this segmented controller now.

Now, upon selection of the segmented controller what you can do is that you can make the label underneath that segment bold and at the same time you can unhide the hidden progress bar for the segment selected. Unbold the unselected label with original font replacement.

Hope you understand with example of providing and seeking segments.

Let me write the code for it, comment if you face any issue:

```
@IBAction func selection(_ sender: Any) {//outlet to UISegmentedControler
        let sel = segmt.selectedSegmentIndex
        if sel == 0 {

            Providing.font = selectedFont //selected font is bold font 
            Seeking.font = fonts //original font for seeking
            p.isHidden = false
            s.isHidden = true


        }
        else if sel == 1 {

            Seeking.font = selectedFont
            Providing.font = fontp //original font for providing
            s.isHidden = false
            p.isHidden = true



        }
        else{
            //code..
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you do is,

- You create a UIView Subclass, you can manually design it by an xib, so that you can reuse the uiview.
- Make it look like a Segmented control, by having two buttons
- subclass UIView and write code for hooking up the two buttons with added animation, where One will get deselected (change color), when other one is selected and vise-versa.

All the Custom Segmented control you see is done like this, with added animation and custom `drawRect`. And the code is much more modular and OOP, so that anyone can use it easily with a very easy and simple public api.

Hope this explanation helps you build your own custom control. 
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `collection view` to create something like this.

Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552321/5716829

After doing minor changes in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` you can create your own custom `segmented control`.

Let me know if you need any help following this approach.